# Python - variable in a for loop acts as if it didn't exist

Tags: python, for-loop

In the all-around context, I have a .csv file which I am reading data from and then I want to know how many rows there are in the file.

I've attempted doing that with this code:

```
for row in CharsDict:
    IDsQuant = sum(1 for row in CharsDict)
IDsQuant = int(IDsQuant)
```

But whenever I try to do something with the variable **IDsQuant** (like the above IDsQuant = int(IDsQuant)), it gives me this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'IDsQuant' referenced before assignment
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: define it before your loop `IDsQuant = 0`. If you don't its only defined in the scope inside the loop which is why you receive the error.

Comment: @Cfreak don't think that helps, if the variable isn't being set as expected by the for loop, then you'll just get a (wrong) answer of 0 every time. Also not necessary because you're not doing `+=` or something that would require it.

Comment: What's the point of using two for loops, it seems IDsQuant would get the same value every time

Comment: @Cfreak, saw your edit, I don't think Python *has* a "loop scope" like this. Anything defined within the loop is available outside it. I think this is more the result of the initial for loop not running on an empty `CharDict`.

Comment: How about: `print len(CharsDict)`

Comment: @JoeR Doing so gives me this error: `TypeError: 'DictReader' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this

```
for row in CharsDict:
    IDsQuant += 1
IDsQuant = int(IDsQuant)
```

is somewhat more effective and useful than

```
for row in CharsDict:
    IDsQuant = sum(1 for row in CharsDict)
IDsQuant = int(IDsQuant)
```

I seem to get no more errors by using this alternative.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You are right in assuming that your code should work, as loops don't create a new scope in Python.

However, if the body of the loop is not executed for some reason (such as `CharsDict` being an empty container), the `IDsQuant` variable will not have been created, generating the error you have seen.

The code below shows an example of this happening --- same code, running with different arguments. In the second call of the example function, the loop will not run, reproducing the situation you have, with the same error.

```
def test_scope(n_loops):                                                     
    for i in range(n_loops):                                                    
        variable = i                                                         
    return variable                                                          


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                   
    print('First test:', test_scope(1))                                      

    print('Empty loop:', test_scope(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined what `CharsDict` is in your example, nor how you are reading the file.

If your "read" returns an array - rows, then just the number of rows will be len (rows).

If OTOH, you are iterating through an iterable, you can increment a count that was set to zero before the iteration starts.